# How do I add characters to the beginning of each collapsed result of paste0?

Tags: r

I'm trying to construct the input json input for mongodb query.

I have a vector that contains ids

```
[1] "62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab" "62708dc95baeeff0a37571ac"
```

I want to create a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[1] [{\"oid\":\"62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab"},{\"oid\":\"62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab"}]
```

so far I have been only able to do this:

```
["{\"oid\":\"62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab,62708dc95baeeff0a37571ac\"}"]
```

using this line of code:

```
sprintf('{"oid":"%s"}', paste0(doc_list, collapse=",")) %>% jsonlite::toJSON()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c("62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab", "62708dc95baeeff0a37571ac")
DF <- data.frame(oid = x)

library(jsonlite)
toJSON(DF)
#[{"oid":"62708dc95baeeff0a37571ab"},{"oid":"62708dc95baeeff0a37571ac"}]
```